# Как выбрать остальные кластеры кроме кликнутого и изменить в них кастомный шаблон иконки на yandex карте?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, cluster

Применил метод при клике на кластер, добавление модификатора на элемент шаблона кластера templateLayoutFactory, но так же необходимо убирать этот класс у всех остальных кластеров на карте, если такой есть...

```
initMap() {
// Инициализация карты
const map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
  center: [45.015792, 39.034979],
  zoom: 15,
  controls: []
}),

// Создаем элемент кластера
createClusterIconLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
  '<div class="map__placemark">' +
  '$[properties.iconLayout]' + '<span class="map__placemark-text">5</span>' +
  '</div>');

const clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
  clusterize: true,
  hasBalloon: false,
  hasHint: false,
  clusterGroupByCoordinates: false,
  clusterOpenBalloonOnClick: true,
  clusterIconLayout: createClusterIconLayout,
  clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
  clusterHideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
  geoObjectHideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
  clusterIconShape: {
    type: 'Rectangle',
    coordinates: [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 40, 40 ] ],
  },
  iconOffset: [ -21, -21 ],
});

this.placeMarks.forEach((placemark, index) => {
  this.geoObjects[index] = new ymaps.Placemark(placemark, {}, {
    iconLayout: createClusterIconLayout,
    iconShape: {
      type: 'Rectangle',
      coordinates: [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 40, 40 ] ],
    },
    iconOffset: [ -21, -21 ],
  });
});

clusterer.add(this.geoObjects);

map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);

// Добавляем активный класс на блок иконки кластера при клике
clusterer.events.add('click', function (e) {

  var clustererPlacemark = e.get('target');
  var overlay = clustererPlacemark.getOverlaySync();
  var layout = overlay.getLayoutSync();
  var element = layout.getParentElement();

  // Здесь пытался найти все кластеры на карте, но выдает объект, а дальше профильтровать, чтобы отключить активный класс на блоке иконки не получается
  // var clusters = clusterer.getClusters();
  //
  // console.log(clusters.filter());

  let customCluster = element.querySelector('.map__placemark');
  if (customCluster.classList.contains('map__placemark--active')) {
    customCluster.classList.remove('map__placemark--active')
  } else {
    customCluster.classList.add('map__placemark--active');
  }
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
clusterer.events.add('click', function (e) {
    const clickedClusterElement = getClusterDomElement(e.get('target'));

    const placemark = clickedClusterElement.querySelector('.map__placemark');
    placemark.classList.toggle('map__placemark--active');

    clusterer.getClusters().forEach(function (cluster) {
        const clusterElement = getClusterDomElement(cluster);
        if (clusterElement !== clickedClusterElement) {
            const placemark = clusterElement.querySelector('.map__placemark');
            placemark.classList.remove('map__placemark--active');
        }
    });
});

function getClusterDomElement(cluster) {
    const overlay = cluster.getOverlaySync();
    const layout = overlay.getLayoutSync();
    return layout.getParentElement();
}
```

Comment: Уже обрадовался когда сделал первый клик на другой кластер, но после второго клика перестает убирать с остальных активный класс, а если приблизить и на трех кластерах пробовать, вообще не работает( . https://jsbin.com/paxoqul/edit?js,output    (вот пример)

Comment: Код рабочий, если дать больше меток. Код работает именно с кластерами, а не с отдельными объектами. Если каждой точке добавить пару с теми же координатами (для простоты), на карте останутся одни лишь кластеры и код будет работать при любом масштабе. https://jsbin.com/yabofixupa/edit?js,output